# Conversation system

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Am trying  to build a conversation system for users on a web app am working on.
At the the moment am quite confused on how to setup the database tables.
for now i have a table with fields this

- C_id
- Message
- S_id
- R_id
- read
- date_time

Comment: Could you give a little more information? What other tables do you have. I am assuming S_id, and R_id are foreign keys referencing other tables. If this assumption is not correct what do S_id and R_id refer to?

Comment: S_id is the sender's user id and R_id is the receiver's user id

Comment: In the year 2011, it's okay to use verbose, self-descriptive column names like `sender_id` and `receiver_id`, especially when you're asking other people for advice.

Comment: you ll need also delete status.  sender or receiver might wish to delete the message, while the other didn't yet.

Comment: What should your "conversation system" be able to do? Is it just for two people to send messages to each other? Could there be be more than two people per conversation? Is there any concept of message sharing/forwarding/redirecting? Should it be just individual messages that are grouped together, or is there more to a "conversation" like inviting additional users to the conversation? You need to give us some more information to go on, otherwise this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is a conversation table (C_id), I would have three tables in all:

1. Conversation
2. Message
3. User

You look to have the third, but have collapsed the other two together. The relevant fields would be:

```
User
   U_id (PK)
Conversation
   C_id (PK)
   R_id (FK on U_id)
   S_id (FK on U_id)
   fields relating to the conversation only - eg  the date-time it started.
Message
   M_id (PK)
   Text
   Date_time
   Has_been_read
   Author_id (FK on U_id)
   Conversation_id (FK on C_id)
```

Comment: I agree with @deceze and his list of questions. My answer above is making assumptions about all these points, and is the simplest way of recording a conversation in table terms.